# minTime and maxTime not working with schedule primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm trying to use schedule of PrimeFaces, i use it with the version `5.1-RC1` the `minTime` and `maxTime` work fine, but when i upgrade to `5.3` or `6.0` it does not work.

```
<p:schedule view="agendaWeek" slotMinutes="30" timeZone="GMT+2" 
            axisFormat="H:mm" locale="fr" maxTime="19" minTime="7"
            value="#{mybean.myModel}" id="idCanlandrier">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('wNew').show();" />
</p:schedule>
```

[image: The correct with version primefaces-5.0-RC1]

[image: The wrong with version primefaces-5.3 and primefaces-6.0]

> Arethere any changes i have to do?

Comment: try to intial minTime and maxTime in the managedBean specifying hours and minutes

Comment: it not work @BillyHope !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use it with `PrimeFaces 5.3` and you can resolve it if you use String value format with Minutes `(":00")` => `maxTime="19:00`"

For me, I have a backingBean return String value like this and it works fine:

```
public String getMaxTime() {
   Integer time=9;
   return time.toString()+":00";
}
```

Hope this solution help you.

Comment: great work, it work for me perfectly thank you very much :)

Comment: Your welcome ! I having the same problem when i upgrade my PrimeFaces

Comment: yes @BillyHope i think your solution was also work, i just don't miss understood, thank you any way